# Why have I counted wrong?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is:

There are 10 questions in an exam. At least 4 of the first 5 questions  must be answered. Then how many ways (combinations) are there to answer 7 questions?

I thought it should be 
${5 \choose 4}{6 \choose 3}$ because there are ${5 \choose 4}$ ways to decide which 4 of the first 5 questions to answer. After that choice is made, we still need to choose 3 more questions to answer from the remaining 6 questions. The number of ways to do this is ${6 \choose 3}$ . Hence I get my answer via the counting principal.

However I think I've overcounted but I don't see how my application of the counting principle is wrong. The counting principal I'm given says that  if there're $m$ ways to do task 1 and after task 1 is done, there're $n$ ways to do task 2 then the total number of ways to do task 1 and task 2 is $mn$.

I now think the answer should in fact be ${5 \choose 4}{5 \choose 3}+{5 \choose 5}{5 \choose 2}$. But I still don't really see why I've counted wrong earlier and why my use of the counting principal is incorrect. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: so we have either  4 or 5 from the original, then how many ways are there to answer three questions plus how many ways to answer two questions+2 is the final count

Comment: Consider your first alternative. If $A$ represents your first four picks, and $B$ your last three, and $\cdot$ is a question you skip, then you are counting $AAAAB\cdot\cdot B\cdot B$ and $ABAAA\cdot\cdot B\cdot B$ separately. They are in fact the same set of questions, hence you are overcounting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every set of $7$ questions that includes all of the first $5$ has been counted $5$ times in your original calculation. Take the set consisting of the first $7$ questions. You’ve counted it once with questions $1,2,3$, and $4$ as the $4$ chosen from the first $5$, once again with questions $1,2,3$, and $5$ as the $4$ chosen from the first $5$, yet again with questions $1,2,4$, and $5$ as the $4$ chosen from the first $5$, once more with questions $1,3,4$ and $5$ as the $4$ chosen from the first $5$, and a fifth and final time with questions $2,3,4$, and $5$ as the $4$ chosen from the first $5$.

Comment: thanks, I see what you're saying. Can you tell me what's wrong with my use of the counting principal though? Does it require some kind of independence between the choices?

Comment: @maths: Yes. Your two choices were from overlapping sets, so it was possible for two different pairs of choices to produce the same final result. The multiplication principle applies only when each combination of choices results in a different outcome.